# How to start a Python script from a ArcGIS Pro AddIn?

Tags: c#, python-addin, arcgis-pro-sdk

I use C# for creating an AddIn for ArcGIS Pro 3.1.

I got a feature request to start a python script (which is part of a toolbox) and pass some arguments.

Unfortunately I found only descriptions about Python scripts in ArcGIS Pro but none of them work with an AddIn.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you explore the sample scripts for the SDK, they have many examples on github such as [CallScriptFromNet](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk-community-samples/tree/master/Geoprocessing/CallScriptFromNet).